# Finding an integer-valued function $f$ such that $\int _0^\infty \frac {f(x)}{3+7a}e^{\frac{-x}{3+7a}}dx=a$ for all $a$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, analysis

> Is there a function $f: \Bbb R \to \Bbb Z$ such that for every $a \in \Bbb N$, the identity
>   $$a=\int _0^\infty \frac {f(x)}{3+7a}\exp(-{\frac{x}{3+7a}})dx$$
>   holds?

When $f=1$ the integral equals $1$, and when $f(x)=\frac 17 (x-3)$ we get the required $a$.

If we take a step function $f$ of the form $n\Bbb 1_{x<t}$ then the integral is equal to $n(1-e^{-\frac{t}{3+7a}})$ and equating with $a$ leads to a dependence of $t$ on $a$, so it does not work. Intuitively a a finite linear combination of functions of this form will not work either as it is a combination of exponentials so cannot give a nonconstant polynomial.

Comment: More generally, $$\int_0^{\infty} \frac{f(x)}{c_0+c_1a}\exp\left(-\frac{x}{c_0+c_1a}\right)\,\mathrm{d}x = a$$ for $f(x) := -\frac{c_0}{c_1}+\frac{1}{c_1}x$.